DGE Analysis using Limma on DSP GeoMx Data: Handling Multiple ROIs per Core
I am performing differential expression analysis using the limma package on DSP GeoMx data, and I have a question regarding the handling of multiple ROIs per core. Below is a snippet of my sample information:
ROIs    Class   Group
A1  pos Pre
A1  neg Pre
A1  neg Pre
B1  pos Post
B1  pos Post
C1  neg Post
C1  pos Post
D1  neg Pre
D1  neg Pre
E1  neg Post
E1  pos Post
F1  pos Pre

The unique patient IDs are A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, and F1.
My aim is to identify DEGs between Pre Vs Post in neg Class and DEGs between Pre Vs Post in pos Class
I have the following questions:

How can I adjust for the subsampling per tissue, considering that the multiple regions of interest placed per tissue section are not independent observations?
How do I create a design formula to incorporate both the Class and Group variables for the limma analysis?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

You might ask this on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/
